# Error running JHipster Registry

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-registry

I'm trying to start [JHipster Registry](http://www.jhipster.tech/jhipster-registry/) by building it from source and for that I'm following [Matt Raible's tutorial](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/06/20/develop-microservices-with-jhipster).

But I'm getting an error with exit code 1 and the following is the generated stack trace.

```
yarn install v0.27.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
warning fsevents@1.1.1: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.1.1" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "angular2-cookie@1.2.6" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/common@^2.0.0".
warning "angular2-cookie@1.2.6" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/core@^2.0.0".
warning "ng2-translate@4.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/core@^2.0.0".
warning "ng2-translate@4.2.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular/http@^2.0.0".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
[1/4] ⢀ node-sass: could not find "C:\Users\Srikar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.EXE". checking
[-/4] ⢀ waiting...
[3/4] ⠠ phantomjs-prebuilt: Receiving...
[-/4] ⠠ waiting...
error D:\JHipster\jhipster-microservices-example\registry\node_modules\node-

sass: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
Arguments: /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
Directory: D:\JHipster\jhipster-microservices-example\registry\node_modules\node-sass
Output:
Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\JHipster\jhipster-microservices-example\registry\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'D:\\JHipster\\jhipster-microservices-example\\registry\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.0
gyp info using node@8.3.0 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\JHipster\jhipster-microservices-example\registry\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\JHipster\jhipster-microservices-example\registry\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\JHipster\jhipster-microservices-example\registry\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\JHipster\jhipster-microservices-example\registry\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\JHipster\jhipster-microservices-example\registry\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\JHipster\jhipster-microservices-example\registry\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (D:\JHipster\jhipster-microservices-example\registry\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (D:\JHipster\jhipster-microservices-example\registry\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (D:\JHipster\jhipster-microservices-example\registry\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\JHipster\jhipster-microservices-example\registry\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\JHipster\jhipster-microservices-example\registry\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at D:\JHipster\jhipster-microservices-example\registry\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21) code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Users\Srikar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.EXE
gyp verb check python version `C:\Users\Srikar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.EXE -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "3.5.4\r\n"
gyp verb could not find "C:\Users\Srikar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.EXE". checking python launcher
gyp verb could not find "C:\Users\Srikar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.EXE". guessing location
gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Users\Srikar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\python.EXE", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (D:\JHipster\jhipster-microservices-example\registry\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:482:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (D:\JHipster\jhipster-microservices-example\registry\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at D:\JHipster\jhipster-microservices-example\registry\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.16251
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\JHipster\\jhipster-microservices-example\\registry\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd D:\JHipster\jhipster-microservices-example\registry\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.3.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

**Steps performed:**

1) Download the [JHipster Registry](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry) from Github as a zip and Unzip it.

2) Navigate to that directory in the Windows PowerShell and run `yarn` or `yarn install`.

I'm new to JHipster. I'm not sure whether the issue is with sass or python2 or other. I'm looking for detailed information regarding the issue and how to solve it?

Node Version: 8.3.0

Power Shell Version: 5.1.16251.0

OS ->

Edition: Windows 10 Enterprise Insider Preview

Version: 1703

OS Build: 16251.1002

[As far as I can understand,

i) Warning with fsevents is because I'm using Windows x-64 and fsevents is mainly for Mac to monitor file systems. Is that correct?

ii) Is the registry using Angular 2 for the front-end design? (even though you can build Angular 4 apps with JHispter)

iii) When building fresh packages, node_sass complains it cannot find the python.exe file but I've checked the folder but the file exists. I have python3.5.4 in the path too.

In the subsequent steps, is it looking for python2 because it didn't find python3? If JHipster is a SpirngBoot(back-end) + Angular(front-end) application then where will the python be used? Can we write mild python scripts too?]

Answer (score 0):

i) correct you can ignore this warning

ii) the registry is an app generated by JHipster (you can see its options in `.yo-rc.json` file) and uses angular 4 for its UI

iii) python is only used for node building not by the app runtime, here the issue is with node-sass that cannot be built and it's an environment issue:

- node-gyp requires python 2.x to build native module like node-sass and you have python 3.x, please re-install
- JHipster recommends using an LTS version of Node currently 6.x, you're using latest currently 8.x, please consider re-installing.

Now, the bad news is that you are on Windows; best platforms for nodejs are Linux and macOS, Matt Raible is on macOS so he did not encounter all your issues. It's possible that even with fixing your python and nodejs versions node-gyp may fail building native modules. If this happens you have few alternatives:

- use [jhipster-devbox](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-devbox)
- don't use sass and [select a tutorial](http://www.jhipster.tech/video-tutorial/) that doesn't use it
- install MS build tools

Comment: I've updated the question with the specified versions. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I just downgrade NodeJS to 6.x and things started to work out. So, please, try downgrade it and recompile using: yarn.